# FileStream и пути длинною >260 символов

Tags: c#, .net

Сначала программа валилась на получении списка фалов через `Directory.GetFiles` с `PathTooLongException`.

Почитал и нашел информацию, о том, что ограничение сняли в последних фреймворках.

Хорошо, сменил версию, но теперь при создании FileStream вылетает `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`.
 с таким стеком:

> в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    в System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
>   Boolean checkHost)    в System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)    в
>   MD5Calculator.Program.Main(String[] args) в E:\Projects!My
>   Projects\MD5Calculator\MD5Calculator\Program.cs:строка 36

Проверил валидность пути путем открытия файла и он успешно открылся.

Получается `FileStream` не поддерживает длинные пути?
Как уйти от этого?

**UPD**

Минимальный код:

```
 var filePath = @"\\?\"+Path.Combine(fileList.Key, list[i].FileName);
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
 {

  }
```

Добавление `@"\\?\"` поменяло исключение на

> System.IO.IOException: 'Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени
>   папки или метке тома

Может быть с шарой такое не работает?

Вот еще пример пути, который вызывает проблему и я немного обфуцировал звездочками:

```
\\******\********\*******\*******************\****************\******\**********  *********\image0000015B0000018B0000027B0000041B0000042B0000046B0000099B0000303B0000363B0000380B0000484B0000563B0000569B0000958B0000959B0000972B0001164B0000025B0000050B0000149A.jpg
```

Comment: E:\Projects!My Projects\MD5Calcula - Восклицательный знак после Projects это нормально?

Comment: @MichaelVaysman да. Но файл лежит совершенно в другом месте.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/307186/ - При использовании префикса “\\?\” мы можем работать с длинными путями как в Win API,
Directory.CreateDirectory("\\\\?\\" + long_dir_name);

Comment: Добавил @"\\?\", но все равно.

Comment: Добавил минимальный код

Comment: @ГеннадийП, кстати после префикса ошибка меняется на System.IO.IOException: 'Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома. Для работы с шарой этот синтаксис работает?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а может речь будет в банальном TriMe?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko где-то лишний пробел? Не похоже. Я в дебагере беру переменную и ее результат копирую в проводник и файл успешно открывается.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, так работает. Можете оформить как ответ. А почему майки могли побоятся заложить эту логику внутрь, что бы внутри все функции сами при необходимости выполняли дополнение?

Comment: И пути длиною в жизнь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для использования длинных сетевых путей к ним добавляется префикс `\\?\UNC\`. См. [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#maxpath)

> А почему майки могли побоятся заложить эту логику внутрь, что бы внутри все функции сами при необходимости выполняли дополнение?

Главным образом, из-за обратной совместимости. Вероятно, какие-то программы могут повести себя странно, если просто так отменить это ограничение. На самом деле, в Windows 10 есть возможность использовать длинные пути без префикса, но для этого нужно задать несколько настроек, как на уровне ОС так и в манифесте приложения: [.NET 4.6.2 and long paths on Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/).

Comment: Т.е я могу либо в манифесте поменять или либо на уровне ОС и все должно работать автоматически? В 2-ух местах не обязательно править?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Насколько я понял, нужно и то и другое сделать. И в групповой политике, и в манифесте, но сам я не пробовал.